# How to improve my clock trace?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, clock

For my current project, I use two [AD9226](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad9226.html) clocked by the same clock oscillator ([SM77H](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/326/sm77h_3.3v-365442.pdf)) at 25 MHz. The image below is a snapshot of my PCB. U1 and U2 are the ADC, and C1 is the clock. I also highlighted the clock trace. The output of both ADCs is connected to an FPGA that would then sample their outputs.

[image]

As you can see, I had to loop the trace connecting C1 and U1. I also had to match the trace length of the C1-U2 with C1-U1.

My question is, is it ok to instead trace the PCB across another layer to shorten the trace length and avoid the looping trace? My PCB has 4 layers (Top, Power Plane, Ground Plane, and Bottom). So, maybe, I would like to put C1 on the Bottom layer and have the clock traces come out at the Top layer near both ADC's clock pins using Vias.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the oscillator? I'd be concerned that it might not be able to drive both ADCs directly.

Comment: @user1850479 Why is this a concern? Are the ADCs somehow unusually high loads?

Comment: As an aside: C1 is a very misleading [reference designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator) for an oscillator, and would make most of us think "capacitor" instead. Consider a more standard prefix like Y or XTAL.

Comment: @user1850479 I have updated the question to include the link to the datasheet if you want to check it out. So far, on the printed and assembled board, both ADCs output just fine though I do find "spikes" in the readings occasionally.

Comment: @Justme Yeah sorry for that. The picture I provided has been edited to omit some components and their labels to improve clarity. Unfortunately, the labels for both ADC and clock were also omitted. So, I had to re-add them, which resulted in a bad designator for the oscillator.